# Com3 nao existe windows form para arduino

Tags: winforms, arduino

Estou tentando criar um programa que mande informaçoes do windows form para o arduino mas um erro diz que o com3 (a porta que estou usando) Nao existe.
Estamos usando as coordenadas xy do mouse para controlar dois servos motores.
Tudo funciona bem, mas depois de alguns segundos o programa para de funcionar e uma mensagem aparece dizendo que a com3 nao existe

Oque fazer?

Comment: Você está usando que linguagem de programação? Tente criar um [mcve] para nos ajudar com a sua dúvida

Comment: Talvez seja mais aconselhável publicar a sua questão aqui: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/